Rolling Friction Value
I came across a recent unrelated question and realised, I cannot consider that:

If the contact surface one of the sliding / rolling bodies is purely smooth / frictionles, then the friction will be zero regardless of how rough the other surface is, due to the following property of rolling friction motion: at every point, the point of contact of the rolling body, i.e., the particle in touch with the other surface is at rest wrt the other surface (applicable even if the rolling body is rough but surface is smooth).

But what if the roughness of the non-smooth surface is extremely high? Like the rolling body encounters a rise in the surface upto half its height? Then by common sense the statement above is contradicted, but I still don'tknow how to prove it. Then by slowly reducing this rise, we slowly decrease the friction, and according to common sense again, the friction ≠ exactly 0, unless both surfaces are 100% smooth.
So my rephrased question is:
Is the bold statement true or false?

You know I want to edit the question this way: Can we say the bold statement is false because a rise high enough can Stop it? Or does a rise not violate the statement because of something I'm missing out?

The statement in bold is incorrect in at least one way:

... the point of contact of the rolling body, i.e., the particle in touch with the other surface is at rest wrt the other surface ...

This is only true if the object is only rolling and not sliding. However, if the object is sliding (and either not rolling at all or sliding as well as rolling) then the contact point is not at rest relative to the surface. And an object can be sliding as well as rolling if (a) friction between the object and the surface is very small or (b) the object is rotating so fast that friction has not yet had time to slow it down to the point where it is not sliding.

The bold statement is true, under certain assumptions. The two assumptions it implicitly makes are:

The object is only rolling and not sliding.
Both surfaces are nearly flat, even if they are not smooth.

I think that the second condition is the more confusing one of the two, so let's examine it in more depth. Ultimately, friction can arise from small bumps on a surface. However, these bumps are very small, even when the friction is very large. If we consider two pieces of sandpaper rubbing against each other, they have a very large coefficient of friction, but the actual variation in height of the surface of the sandpaper is small.
So to answer your question, both your example and the bold statement are 'correct,' but they apply to different regimes. The bold statement applies to situations where the bumps on the surfaces are much smaller than the size of the rolling object. If you look around, this assumption applies very broadly. It holds for concrete, stone, wood, metal, or basically any other material, even though some of these materials have very high coefficients of friction.

Frictionless would mean that energy was not lost, it did not transfer away.
Energy is transferred by force over distance. If the two bodies could be so rigid that
the protrusions on the lower surface never moved at all, as in your quote, then that would be frictionless,
but impossible, because infinite force would be needed to instantly change the path of the rolling body.
Perfectly rigid bodies produce physics contradictions.
The rolling body must cause the protrusions to flex.
If the protrusions crushed or deformed, then energy would be lost to breaking of internal bonds. Not frictionless.
If the protrusions flexed, but then, as the rolling body passed, acting as a spring, gave the energy back
to the rolling body, that could be frictionless. In general, I would GUESS that many kinds of protrusions
would not give all the energy back.
So I would think the roughness would cause friction.
